# Getting duplicate value output from rest service while running the URI

Tags: java, rest, web-services

```
package Book;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/resrtest")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Student datareturn() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("ram");
        student.setAge(29);
        student.setSection("A");
        student.setRoll(11);
        student.setFathername("sam");
        student.setSchoolname("ANC");

        return student;
    }
}
```

Output:

> {"Name":"ram","Roll":11,"age":29,"fathername":"sam","name":"ram","roll":11,"schoolname":"ANC","section":"A"}

Why Name and Roll is repeating?

Comment: Please share your Student class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at repeatable values' case.

{"**N**ame":"ram","**R**oll":11,"age":29,"fathername":"sam","**n**ame":"ram","**r**oll":11,"schoolname":"ANC","section":"A"}

You've probably defined additional getter() methods with provided case sensitive names. If you use Jackson. It automatically scans for *getSomething()* methods and adds return values to JSON body.

Change your *Name* and *Roll* fields to small case (Name -> name, Roll -> roll). Then duplication will be removed.

Comment: @DAWN Updated the answer based on your Student class